# Proving that a specific stopping time is finite a.s.

Tags: martingales, stopping-times

I was trying to prove that some specific stopping time is finite almost surely (which was given), but I got stuck and was hoping someone could help me out. The setting is like this: $X_i \sim N(0,1)$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$, $S_0 = 0$, $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ for $n \geq 1$ and $\tau = \inf\{n \in \mathbb{N}: S_n > 1\}$.

Now we want to show that $P(\tau = \infty) = 0$. I have the feeling as if we want to use the Kolmogorov Doob inequality here (note $S_n$ is just an additive martingale), which is:
$$
P(\max_{1\leq k \leq n}S_k \geq \epsilon n) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}(|S_n|)}{n\epsilon}.
$$
For $\epsilon > 0$ I thought we could use this in the following way:
$$
P(\tau=\infty) \leq P(\tau>n) \leq P(\max_{1\leq k \leq n}S_k \leq 1).
$$
But note that here we actually want the inequality inside the probability to be reversed, since then we can just take $\epsilon=\frac{1}{n}$ and we can use the inequality above. But it really seems that we need this here, since the event that the stopping time $\tau$ is larger than $n$ is a subset of the event that the maximum over all $k$ from $1$ to $n$ of $S_k$ is smaller or equal to one, as otherwise we would already have that $\tau \leq n$.

**Thoughts**

Am I using the Kolmogorov Doob inequality wrong? Can we transform it such that it makes our argument work? Is it correct that $\tau > n$ is a subset of $\{\max_{1\leq k \leq n}S_k \leq 1\}$? Maybe  this can be proven in another way, but I am really not sure. We have used nowhere that our $X_n$ are normally distributed, which also could be of great use.

Comment: Assuming the $X_i$ are independent, isn't $S_n \sim N(0,n)$?

Comment: Hi Teresa, I know but I am not sure how this could be used. Maybe a Borel cantelli proof can be used to show that $S_n$ will infinitely often be larger than one? But we cant use the Borel Cantelli lemma in the almost sure direction right because of the missing independence of the $S_n$

Comment: By the central limit theorem (a sum of iid random variables) we have $\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} \to N(0,1)$ in distribution. In particular, if $\tau = \infty$ then $\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}} \to 0$, which happens with zero probability. I am sure we can justify this in some way like that, of course I must be more rigorous but this is the idea.